# Gerar um PDF e gravar dados no banco no Mesmo form

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, input

Tenho um programa que pega o nome e email do cliente para cadastrar no banco e gerar um pdf com esses dados. Mas não consigo mandar os dados do cadastro para o arquivo que gera o pdf. Ou funciona o cadastro no banco ou funciona o pdf. Já usei Ajax pra submeter para arquivos diferentes mas não funciona. 
O ideal seria gerar o pdf após gravar esses dados no banco mas também não funciona.

Formulário:

```
<form action="incluirProfessor.php" method="POST"> 
<!--Entrada dados --> 
<label for="nomeprof"> Nome: </label> <input name="nomeprof" type="text"/>
<label for="emailprof">eMail: </label> <input name="emailprof" type="email"/>
<input type="submit" name="Convidar" value="Convidar" /> 
</form>
```

Include:

```
  // incluirProfessor.php

  require 'conexao.php';
  if (isset($_POST["Convidar"])) {

  mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  $nome  = $_POST["nomeprof"];
  $email = $_POST["emailprof"];

  // Guardando a instrução sql para inclusao
  $sqlinc = "insert into professor(Prof_Nome,Prof_Email) values ('$nome','$email')";

  // submetendo inserção à conexão, se algo der errado paramos a execução com DIE

  if ($con->query($sqlinc) === TRUE) {
  echo "<script>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!'); </script>";
  } else {
  echo "<script>alert('Ocorreu algum erro! Seu cadastro não foi concluído com sucesso.');</script>";
  echo "Error deleting record: " .$con->error;
  }
  mysqli_close($con); 
  exit;
}
```

PDF:

```
<?php   
use Dompdf\Dompdf; 
require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php"); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$nomeprof = $_POST["nomeprof"]; 
$emailprof = $_POST["emailprof"]; 
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y'); 
$from = "CordenadoriaInformatica@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Convite para o sistema InfoQT"; 
$site = "www.infoqt.com.br"; 
$dompdf->load_html("Mensagem enviada"); 
$dompdf->render(); //Exibibir a página 
$dompdf->stream( "relatorio_celke.pdf", array( "Attachment" => false //Para realizar o download somente alterar para true ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Mostre seu código para que fique mais fácil ajudar você.

Comment: O primeiro é o form do programa. O segundo o include. Eles dois funcionam perfeitamente sem o PDF. Com o PDF ele n funciona.